# this is my code and the onClick method's else if condition is not going to next activity after clicking ImageButton twitter

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dref=database.getReference();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        findViewById(R.id.twitter).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.google).setOnClickListener(this);



                // Configure Google Sign In
                 gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.web_client_id))
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();
                // [END config_signin]
                mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

                // [START initialize_auth]
                // Initialize Firebase Auth
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                // [END initialize_auth]
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            WelcomeActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                assert account != null;
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            }  catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this,"Google Sign In Failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    // [END onactivityresult]

    private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
        // Write new user
        writeNewUser(user.getUid(), user.getDisplayName(), user.getEmail());
        // Go to MainActivity
        startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
        User user = new User(name, email);

        dref.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
    }

    // [START auth_with_google]
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        onAuthSuccess(Objects.requireNonNull((Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())).getUser()));
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this,"Google Sign In Failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signInGoogle() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.google) {
            signInGoogle();
            finish();
        }
        else if (i == R.id.twitter)
        {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,TwitterLoginActivty.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    // [END auth_with_google]
}
```

Comment: the code you edited is also not working @jakir Hossain

Comment: the app crashes when i click on the imagebutton

Comment: I did not edit your code, I just improved your question format.

Comment: oh!! can you help me with the code its not working

Comment: Also add your layout `activity_welcome`

Answer (score 0):

Use `YourActivityName.this` instead of `this`

Because when you use only "this", it refers to the current `context`. And in your case, you are using `this` inside the `onClick` and it refers to the `OnClickListener`(an anonymous class), not to the `activity`.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.google) {
            signInGoogle();
            finish();
        }
        else if (i == R.id.twitter)
        {
        Intent intent=new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this,TwitterLoginActivty.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: If i use Welcomeactivity.this it says  ')' expected

Comment: I think you are missing something in your code. review your code carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing **"this"** as a context reference inside onClick it will pass onClickListener instance instead of your activity, you should pass **"WelcomeActivity.this"**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.google) {
        signInGoogle();
        finish();
    }
    else if (i == R.id.twitter)
    {
    Intent intent=new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this,TwitterLoginActivty.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```